# Notification when the status on sql server replication is "Not Running"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, replication

We have a lot of replications set up. Sometimes for some reason, the status of the replication changes to "Not Running/Expired Soon or Expired". Could you please let me know if there is a way we can receive alerts when the status changes on a particular replication.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please let me know if there is a way we can receive alerts when the status changes on a particular replication.

You can achieve that using [Replication Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/administration/configure-predefined-replication-alerts-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16)

e.g. Below will set up alert for `Replication: agent retry`. Note that you must have database mail enabled and configured as well as sql agent operator configured.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_alert @name=N'Replication: agent retry', 
        @message_id=14152, 
        @severity=0, 
        @enabled=0, 
        @delay_between_responses=0, 
        @include_event_description_in=5, 
        @category_name=N'Replication', 
        @job_id=N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

Refer to : [All About Automatically Monitoring Replication Agent Failures](https://repltalk.com/2010/05/09/all-about-automatically-monitoring-replication-agent-failures/)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your response, I forgot to mention I am using sql server 2005. Is this applicable to 2005 version ?

Comment: @user3063530 yes, it works on 2005 as well